# How to fix "Killed: 9" error in mac os?

Tags: macos, command-line

Since I upgraded my Mac OS, some programs get this error when running:

```
Killed: 9
```

I even execute them via `sudo` but they won't work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 43):

Open a new terminal window/tab

Answer (score 18):

If you replace a signed macOS binary by using `cp` instead of `mv` then macOS caches the signature, doesn't like the look of it because the file changed and kills your process when you try and start the new binary.  Clearly, this is a bug in macOS.  We had to update our install scripts to copy the file a different way.

Comment: I find the terminal CLI enormously useful for debugging network rout problems and service analysis.  Unfortunately Apple does not understand that SSH cannot replace this in their responses of "just use SSH, it's more secure" Unfortunately with the update to macOS 12, I'm now getting a `Killed: 9`. I remember when Mac == Easy back in the 90's

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I solved the `Killed: 9` error, by running `rm` then `cp` instead of just `cp`. Do you have a reference on this problem ?

Comment: I had the same when I upgraded a binary `azcopy` by copying the newer version over the top of it.   I had used `xattr` to remove `com.apple.quarantine` and `com.apple.macl` attributes so this may have had some bearing on it as well.  A reboot actually reverted the `azcopy` binary back to the previous version.

Answer (score 4):

1. Download [UPX](https://upx.github.io). For example, using Homebrew, run `brew install upx`.
2. Decompress the binary:

   ```
   upx -d /path/to/App.app/MacOS/App
   ```

Also see [“This UPX compressed binary contains an invalid Mach-O header and cannot be loaded.”](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/251808/37797)

Comment: Dang! My compressed binaries used to work fine on the M1, but something changed over the last couple of months and they no long work when run through `upx` =(

Comment: The executable being killed isn't compressed with `upx`, how does this have any effect?

Answer (score 0):

in my case there was some process called syspolicy or something like that, once i killed that process, running my command python3 no longer returned killed 9.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it after running this command found [in this homebrew github discussion](https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/439#discussioncomment-261267):

```
brew reinstall pcre2 gettext
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me:

```bash
codesign --sign - --force --preserve-metadata=entitlements,requirements,flags,runtime <path-to-binary>
```

this command replaces the current signature in the binary file with a new one preserving the old information, in this way you reset the previous one that "alarms" the OS. more info [here](https://unix.com/man-page/osx/1/codesign)

[original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51833310/what-is-killed9-and-how-to-fix-in-macos-terminal/77907937#77907937)

Answer (score -1):

I tried resetting the binaries and it did fix the issue for me. To reset the binaries for the macOS M1 terminal, you can follow these steps:

1. Open the Terminal application on your Mac.
2. Type the following command and press Enter: `echo $PATH`. This will display the current path for the terminal.
3. Copy the output of the command and save it in a text editor for reference.
4. Type the following command and press Enter: `echo $SHELL`. This will display the current shell being used by the terminal.
5. If the output of the command is `/bin/bash`, type the following command and press Enter: `nano ~/.bash_profile`. If the output is `/bin/zsh`, type the following command and press Enter: `nano ~/.zshrc`. This will open the shell configuration file in the nano text editor.
6. Scroll down to the bottom of the file and add the following line: `export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin`. This will reset the path to the default macOS path.
7. Save the file by pressing Control+O, then press Enter to confirm, and then exit the editor by pressing Control+X.
8. Type the following command and press Enter: `source ~/.bash_profile` or `source ~/.zshrc`, depending on which shell you are using.
9. Type the following command and press Enter: `echo $PATH`. This will display the new path for the terminal.
10. Verify that the path is correct by running a command that is installed by default on macOS, such as `ls` or `pwd`.

These steps should reset the binaries for the terminal and restore the default macOS path.